# Angular: Calling SelectedTabChange only for rendered tabs

Tags: angular, typescript, rendering, angular-material2, mat-tab

I have a group of tabs in Angular material tab group as below and calling a method `setGridHeight` in **every component ( every tab )**.

```
<mat-tab-group [dynamicHeight]="true" (selectedTabChange)='queue0.setGridHeight();queue1.setGridHeight();queue2.setGridHeight();'>
  <mat-tab *ngIf='showQueues[0]'>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <i class="fa fa-share-square" routerLink="/queue/0" style="color: rgb(8, 148, 148)"></i>Queue 0
    </ng-template>
    <fph-queue-0 #queue0 [rowData]="queue0Items$ | async">
    </fph-queue-0>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf='showQueues[1]'>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <i class="fa fa-share-square" routerLink="/queue/1" style="color: rgb(8, 148, 148)"></i>Queue 0
    </ng-template>
    <fph-queue-1 #queue1 [rowData]="queue1Items$ | async">
    </fph-queue-1>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf='showQueues[2]'>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <i class="fa fa-share-square" routerLink="/queue/2" style="color: rgb(8, 148, 148)"></i>Queue 0
    </ng-template>
    <fph-queue-2 #queue2 [rowData]="queue2Items$ | async">
    </fph-queue-2>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

So in the TS code in every component I am calling a method called **setGridHeight** which is called on tab change.

The issue is if I control the components redering through `*ngIf`, the `selectedtabChange` call throws an error ( since it cant call a method of an unrendered component( unrendered tab) )

How do I then change the call to only methods from only rendered components ( tabs ).

for ex:
`showQueues = [true, false, true];`

`showQueues[1] = false`
and is not rendered and thus `queue1.setGridHeight()` throws an exception
`Cannot read property 'setGridHeight' of undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You should ideally set single template variable name to all tab content like `#queue` and there after query all the rendered component by using `ViewChildren` like below

```
@ViewChildren('queue', {read: ViewContainerRef}) queue;
```

> `ViewContainerRef` is must to grab reference of that component.

It will return rendered tab that has `#queue` template variable, now you can easily loop over each tab on `selectedTabChange` event.

```
onTabChanged () {
    this.queue.forEach(q => q.setGridHeight());
}
```

[**Demo Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-let3j6?file=app/tab-group-dynamic-height-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

One of the quickest solution would be to change `*ngIf` to `[hidden]`

```
<mat-tab-group [dynamicHeight]="true" (selectedTabChange)='queue0.setGridHeight();queue1.setGridHeight();queue2.setGridHeight();'>
  <mat-tab [hidden]='!showQueues[0]'>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <i class="fa fa-share-square" routerLink="/queue/0" style="color: rgb(8, 148, 148)"></i>Queue 0
    </ng-template>
    <fph-queue-0 #queue0 [rowData]="queue0Items$ | async">
    </fph-queue-0>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab [hidden]='!showQueues[1]'>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <i class="fa fa-share-square" routerLink="/queue/1" style="color: rgb(8, 148, 148)"></i>Queue 0
    </ng-template>
    <fph-queue-1 #queue1 [rowData]="queue1Items$ | async">
    </fph-queue-1>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab [hidden]='!showQueues[2]'>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <i class="fa fa-share-square" routerLink="/queue/2" style="color: rgb(8, 148, 148)"></i>Queue 0
    </ng-template>
    <fph-queue-2 #queue2 [rowData]="queue2Items$ | async">
    </fph-queue-2>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the ‘queue1’ is not undefined and not null:

```
If (undefined !== queue1 && queue1 != null) {
  queue1.setGridHeight();
}
```